# ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: django, linux, containers, azure-web-app-service, pyodbc

I'm deploying a Django app with MSSQL to Azure app service using Docker containers and bumped into the above issue.

`('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

When I finished building the image locally, I started it and everything works fine on localhost.

However, after pushing it to the container registry (which will auto push to the app service), it doesn't work. I turned DEBUG mode to be True and got the above issue.

I've looked around and all the questions asked seem to be irrelevant.

Here's my docker setup

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates \
    && curl -k https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl -k https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2
```

Hope someone can help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using the [odbcinst](https://github.com/gordthompson/odbcinst) module to report the version of unixODBC that Django is working with.

Comment: This is also being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/805).